# Packaging python project - Adding "plugins" to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python packaging, and have an external requirement that some plugins be in the PYTHONPATH environment variable to run correctly.

Is it possible/recommended to accomplish this with the following directory structure?

`./setup.py
./plugin1.py
./plugin2.py
./mypackage/__init__.py
./mypackage/mypackage.py`

So when installed, it would install to:

`%PythonInstallDir%/Lib/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py2.7.egg`

And contain the files:

`%PythonInstallDir%/Lib/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/plugin1.py
%PythonInstallDir%/Lib/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/plugin2.py
%PythonInstallDir%/Lib/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/mypackage/__init__.py
%PythonInstallDir%/Lib/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/mypackage/mypackage.py`

Is this possible/recommended? If so, how would you create a setup.py to achieve this output?

Comment: I think you can add them to `setup` as `py_modules = ['plugin1', 'plugin2']` and they will end up in the same directory as normal single file modules. If a plugin uses the same name as another module, things will go poorly. Some may be annoyed that there are not-really-a-module things in the module path.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the scripts `plugin1.py` and `plugin2.py` you add them via the `scripts` argument. The packages you distribute are defined using the `packages` argument and should list all directories with an own `__init__.py` like so

```
setup(
    ...,
    scripts=['plugin1.py', 'plugin2.py'],
    packages=['mypackage', 'mypackage.mysubpackage'],
    ....
)
```

The correct way to handle dependencies on **external** packages (e.g. from PyPI) in `setup.py` would be to define the `install_requires` argument in `setup(...)`, e.g.

```
setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=['numpy'],
    ....
)
```

I recommend to have a look at the [tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#basic-use) at PythonHosted.org or the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) of the distutils package.